# В laravel The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel

Всем доброго вечера. Вышла эта ошибка - понимаю почему.`The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`
//Это view

```
<form action='{{ url("edit/".$agent->ORG_ID) }}'   method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
```

//Контроллер

```
public function agentUpdate(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $agent = Agent::findOrFail($id);
        $agent ->$request['ORG_ID'];
        $agent ->$request['ORG_NAME'];
        $agent ->$request['EMAIL'];
        $agent -> Hash::make($request['PASSWORD']);
        $agent ->$request['ORG_ABBREV'];
        $agent ->$request['REF_TOWN'];
        $agent ->$request['PHONE1'];
        $agent ->$request['PHONE2'];
        $agent ->$request['FAX'];
        $agent ->$request['MANAGER'];
        $agent ->$request['HTL_SC'];
        $agent ->$request['DOGOVOR_DATE'];
        $agent ->$request['DOGOVOR_N'];
        $agent ->$request['ADDRESS'];
        $agent ->$request['INN'];
        $agent ->$request['RS'];
        $agent ->$request['REF_DEPT'];
        $agent ->$request['IATA_NUMBER'];
        $agent ->$request['ACTIVE_DT'];
        $agent ->$request['MFO'];

        $agent->update();
    
        return redirect('/');
       

    }
//РОУТЕР
Route::get('/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'agentUpdate']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что сохранение идет по методу `PUT`, о чём Вам и говорится в ошибке

> Метод PUT не поддерживается для этого пути. Поддерживаемые методы: GET, HEAD.

Пишите так, будет работать:

```
Route::put('/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'agentUpdate']);
```